# Working with MongoDB field name with special character

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am a newbie to mongodb.
I want to write a query to print part of the column from database.

Here is the data,

```
{
    "user-id" : "u1",
    "username" : "amy",
},
{
    "user-id" : "u2",
    "username" : "billy",
},
{
    "user-id" : "u3",
    "username" : "charlie",
},
{
    "user-id" : "u4",
    "username" : "david",
}
```

It's working fine if I print the "username" with

```
db.user.find().forEach(
    function(myDoc) {
        print( "user: " + myDoc.username );
    });
```

But I can't print the fields with a hyphen in it,

```
db.user.find().forEach(
    function(myDoc) {
        print( "user: " + myDoc.user-id );
    });
```

Error:

```
Error: Line 3: Unexpected token (
```

I tried "user-id", "user-id", but its not work.
How do I print the fields with a hyphen in it?
Thanks.

Comment: `myDoc["user-id"]`. Give me a moment to reference you to one of the many times this question has been asked.

Comment: Also: basic JavaScript.

Comment: Oh. it's so simple... just an array... I spent half an hour on this... Thanks a lot.